# No body content response & only show header in SSL client HTTP GET/POST C program

Tags: c, ssl

I try a C program for extracting remote SSL site page content with openSSL as follows that is  based on the example code from internet google search.
I complile it with "gcc -Wall -lssl -lcrypto -o sslclient sslclient.c" that works

When you run at linux console command with

./ssclient example.com / GET

that will get response from the https://example.com site BUT it always shows/echo out the header information only with HTTP 200 ok response and NO any response body content. Why ? I worked with HTTP option setting such as Accept,Content-type,Connection but it's not able to solve issue. Why ? Please advise. Even I try other remote https website, it is still no body response content except header information. Could you help to try compile the sslclient.c by gcc and run it at your side so you can see what I say ?

```
  /* sslclient.c */ 
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  #include <netdb.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <openssl/rand.h>
  #include <openssl/ssl.h>
  #include <openssl/err.h>
  #define MAXLINE 4096 
  #define MAXSUB  4096
  // Simple structure to keep track of the handle, and
  // of what needs to be freed later.
  typedef struct {
  int socket;
  SSL *sslHandle;
  SSL_CTX *sslContext;
  } connection;

  // For this example, we'll be testing on openssl.org
  #define PORT 443

  // Establish a regular tcp connection
  int tcpConnect (char * str)
  {
  int error, handle;
  struct hostent *host;
  struct sockaddr_in server;

  host = gethostbyname (str);
  handle = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (handle == -1)
  {
   perror ("Socket");
   handle = 0;
  }
   else
  {
   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server.sin_port = htons (PORT);
   server.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *) host->h_addr);
   bzero (&(server.sin_zero), 8);

   error = connect (handle, (struct sockaddr *) &server,
                   sizeof (struct sockaddr));
  if (error == -1)
    {
      perror ("Connect");
      handle = 0;
    }
   }

  return handle;
  }

  // Establish a connection using an SSL layer
  connection *sslConnect (char *str)
  {

    connection *c;
    c = malloc (sizeof (connection));
    c->sslHandle = NULL;
    c->sslContext = NULL;

    c->socket = tcpConnect (str);
    if (c->socket)
     {
      // Register the error strings for libcrypto & libssl
      SSL_load_error_strings ();
      // Register the available ciphers and digests
      SSL_library_init ();

      // New context saying we are a client, and using SSL 2 or 3
      c->sslContext = SSL_CTX_new (SSLv23_client_method ());
    if (c->sslContext == NULL)
     ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);

     // Create an SSL struct for the connection
     c->sslHandle = SSL_new (c->sslContext);
    if (c->sslHandle == NULL)
     ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);

     // Connect the SSL struct to our connection
     if (!SSL_set_fd (c->sslHandle, c->socket))
       ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);

     // Initiate SSL handshake
     if (SSL_connect (c->sslHandle) != 1)
      ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
    }
     else
    {
     perror ("Connect failed");
    }
     return c;
    }

     // Disconnect & free connection struct
     void sslDisconnect (connection *c)
     {
      if (c->socket)
      close (c->socket);
      if (c->sslHandle)
     {
      SSL_shutdown (c->sslHandle);
      SSL_free (c->sslHandle);
      }
      if (c->sslContext)
      SSL_CTX_free (c->sslContext);

      free (c);
     }

     // Read all available text from the connection
     char *sslRead (connection *c)
     {
        const int readSize = 1024;
        char *rc = NULL;
        int received, count = 0;
        char buffer[1024];

      if (c)
       {
         while (1)
          {
            if (!rc)
              rc = malloc (readSize * sizeof (char) + 1);
            else
            rc = realloc (rc, (count + 1) *
                      readSize * sizeof (char) + 1);

           received = SSL_read (c->sslHandle, buffer, readSize);
           buffer[received] = '\0';
           if (received > 0){
             strcat (rc, buffer);
           }
           if (received < readSize)
            break;
          count++;
          }
         }

          return rc;
           }

          // Write text to the connection
          void sslWrite (connection *c, char *text)
            {
              if (c)
               SSL_write (c->sslHandle, text, strlen (text));
             }

           // Very basic main: we send GET / and print the response.
           int main (int argc, char *argv[])
               {
                 connection *c;
                 char *response;
                 char *str="";

             if (strcmp(argv[3],"GET")==0) {
               str="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
               argv[4]="";
               }
             if (strcmp(argv[3],"POST")==0) {
               str="Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
              }
              char sendline[MAXLINE + 1];
              int d;
              d=strlen(argv[4]);

              snprintf(sendline, MAXSUB,
                  "%s %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                  "Host: %s\r\n"
                  "%s\r\n"
                  "Content-length: %d\r\n\r\n"
                  "%s", argv[3],argv[2], argv[1],str,d, argv[4]); 


              c = sslConnect (argv[1]);
              sslWrite (c, sendline);
              response = sslRead (c);
              printf ("%s\n", response);
              sslDisconnect (c);
              free (response);

               return 0;
               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       if (received < readSize)
        break;
```

You are assuming that `SSL_read` will only return fewer bytes then `readSize` if no more data are available. But instead SSL_read will return at most data from the same SSL frame and often the HTTP header is sent in a different SSL frame then the HTTP body. Apart from that you make the typical mistakes when writing you own HTTP client:

- Assume that read will return once all data are available. This is only the case if the server closes the connection after the response which it will not do immediately with HTTP keep alive. By doing a HTTP/1.1 request without Connection header you tell the server that it might use HTTP keep alive.
- Assume the content will be a single string. But by sending a HTTP/1.1 request you tell the server that it might reply with HTTP chunked mode.

If you care about simplicity and not performance and just want to learn how HTTP works than start with HTTP/1.0 instead. If you care about performance learn about HTTP by reading the standard and try to implement everything on your own or use existing HTTP stacks.

Comment: thanks for your reply, comment it will help to solve it ? But I tried it ,it didn't works and got worser

Comment: How about add "Connection: close" to ask server to  close connection ?

Comment: @aabb: unfortunately you are too far away from a proper solution. I recommend to get first the HTTP part right and then add the TLS part. Apart from that you will find lots of questions here from people which tried to implement their own HTTP stacks so I recommend to look first for existing questions and answers once you run into problems.

Comment: @aabb: Connection close will not solve the problem with HTTP chunked mode.

Comment: Actually I  m done this  in curl php but the speed is too slow in term of 3 to 10 seconds so I go back to C program

Comment: @aabb: that's probably not a problem of curl vs. C. Have a look at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) for using curl in C but it might also simply be a problem which is outside of PHP or C, i.e. slow DNS lookups etc. Apart from that you fail to do proper validation of certificates.

Comment: You mean remote certificate check  may  not  be valid so that I may NOT get body content response ?

Comment: http://fm4dd.com/openssl/sslconnect.htm, this link seems better way to check to cerfiicate  than  I post it

Comment: @aabb: I mean you are not doing a proper certificate check and thus your code is open to man-int-the-middle attacks. This has nothing to do with failure to get the body. And the example code you've linked to fails to do proper checks too.

Comment: How about I start to study this HP's client-server program to  at this link , http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/83final/ba554_90007/ch05.html?btnNext=next%C2%A0%EF%BF%BD,  Is it good program to avoid man-in-the-middle ? Please advise. Thanks great reply anyway

Comment: @aabb: this sample program at least checks against the certificate chain but still fails to check the hostname against the certificate and is thus still open to man-in-the-middle attacks. I really recommend against implementing TLS and HTTP on your own, at least not with the experience you currently have. It is more complex than you might think.

Answer (score 1):

If `SSLread()` function is replaced by the following code, all body contents 
response will be shown with header information exactly, and the hints are based from the link at  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217101 and Steffen 
Ullrich's reply post in this thread. And at remote server, create response php page and use $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is on or not to verify the HTTPS site is accessed or not for testing. And no need Connection and Keep-Alive option.

```c
char buf[1024];
int bytes;
memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
bytes = SSL_read(c->sslHandle, buf, sizeof(buf));
while (bytes > 0) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, bytes);
    memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
    bytes = SSL_read(c->sslHandle, buf, sizeof(buf));
}
```